# Android, how to reduce the height of image in image adapter?

Tags: android, gridview, height, imageview

In my activity i have to show some images. I used gridview in my activity and each row should shows 4 images (width of each image is 25% of screen). i need to reduce the height of image in same size with width.

So, in my UI i have a gridview and my imageAdapter arranges picture into screen. this is the code of adapter:

```
public class ContestantsPhotoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater myInflater;
    private Bitmap[] bitmapList;


    public ContestantsPhotoAdapter(Context c) {
        myInflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    public void setData(Bitmap[] bmImages){ 
        bitmapList = bmImages;  

        Log.i("ContestantsPhotoAdapter", "Images passed to the adapter.");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bitmapList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = myInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_contestantsphoto, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.ivIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imvContestantsPhoto_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmapList[position]);

        return convertView;
    }   

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
    }
}
```

grid_contestantsphoto.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ImageView
    xmlns:android                   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id                      = "@+id/imvContestantsPhoto_icon"
    android:layout_width            = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height           = "100dip"
    android:contentDescription      = "@string/menu_contentdescription" />
```

My problem is when i change `android:layout_height = "100dip"` it doesn't take effect and always the height is same as before.

Please tell me how to reduce the size. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference. I changed the adapter code to this:

```
public void setData(Bitmap[] bmImages){ 
        bitmapList = bmImages;  

        for(int i=0; i < bitmapList.length; i++){
            bitmap = bitmapList[i];
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getWidth(), false);
            bitmapList[i] = bitmap;
        }
        Log.i("ContestantsPhotoAdapter", "Images passed to the adapter.");
    }
```

Now, the height of images are as same as width.

Answer (score 0):

This realy works for me! Please try this!

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/productImage"
        android:layout_width="100px"
        android:layout_height="100px"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/loading" />
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately did not worked. still height is as same as original one.

Comment: Thanks again but i think this is not the correct way because nothing takes effect.